# Is it possible to test jest tests?

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs

I want to make a tool that test different exercises. One exercise is unit-testing. Therefore I need to test whether the tests that are made by the student are good tests. So for example the student has the following code:

```
export class HelloWorld {
  public static showHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

With the following jest test:

```
import { HelloWorld } from '..';

describe(Hello World exercise, () => {
  test('Check function is defined', () => {
    expect(HelloWorld.showHello()).toBeDefined();
  });

  test('Empty input results in Hello World!', () => {
    expect(HelloWorld.showHello()).toBe('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

How can I test that the student did indeed test these two tests? I thought about

```
export const firstTest = test()...
```

And then test whether firstTest test the right thing. But the disadvantage is that you have to export every test for this solution.

Comment: Typically, you would do this 1 of 2 ways.  First, define a public interface your students must implement and write unit tests to that public interface.  Then you can just run your tests against their code.  If it works, they wrote good code and good tests.  This method gives you some confidence in the quality of the tests.  Second is by mere visual inspection.  You can augment visual inspection with a code coverage tool.  I don't know what jest uses, but istanbul is pretty popular in JS in general.

Comment: do you provide code that should be covered with tests? or is it provided by students also?

Comment: Thanks @c1moore, this will help by inspecting there code. But that will not test there tests right? They can for example test 'true'.toBe('true').

Comment: And @skyboyer, the students should indeed write both, the code and the test. So in above example, the student should also have written the HelloWorld class

Comment: I believe it is not possible to validate tests written for custom code. why? because otherwise it would be part of software development process. But currently we are able just to calculate coverage for tests and that's all. But if task is changed to "write custom tests for predefined code" then you would be able to prepare some "intentionally broken" code that should lead good tests to fail. So far you could validate tests in automatic way.

Comment: They _could_ still due that, hence the code coverage tool to confirm they are actually testing their code.  A combination of the methods I gave above is likely the best approach short of manually reviewing the tests.  If you test your students' tests, you might as well just read all of their tests and determine if they do anything manually.

Comment: There are also methods of trying to find bugs in large code bases.  One thing I have seen is purposefully adding bugs to the code and having developers find the bug (naturally through testing).  You could take this approach by purposefully breaking your students' code and seeing if their tests catch the bug.  Maybe break the code in 10 places and see how many of the 10 places get caught.  Whatever code coverage you find acceptable would get an A.  For example, if you want 80% code coverage, 8/10 bugs should be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Testing tests requires black box testing, which means you either need to know which tests are written before hand (and how they should be written) or you need review each test and write unique tests for each one.  Given you are trying to test students' understanding of tests and do this in an automated way, I doubt either option is plausible.

However, there are several heuristics you can use.  I suggest using a combination of the first 3 of these methods.

1. Define a public interface your students *must* implement and write tests to this public interface.  This doesn't directly test your students' tests, but if any of your tests fail, they did not write sufficient (quality) tests.  These tests should be easy and obvious for your students should focus on.
2. Use a code coverage tool such as [istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/).  This doesn't test the quality of the tests directly, but it does give you confidence that the tests actually touch the code.
3. This method is *inspired* by (not an implementation of) a technique I recently discovered called "Adversarial Gamedays".  For this method, you would random break the student's code in several places, let's just say 10, and let the code run.  Chances are the tests won't catch all of the bugs you made, but they should catch x%, where x is the acceptable code coverage you determined.  The bugs should be sufficiently spread across the program so as not to take advantage of a single flaw.  This tests both quantity and quality.
4. Visual inspection and/or manual testing.  This method is error-prone and time consuming.  If you don't have TAs, it's probably not a viable option.  However, if you spend sufficient time on this method, it is the most thorough and least biased.

As I stated, a combination of the first 3 options would be optimal.  For example, provide a public interface for the system, run code coverage tools, and randomly break y areas of each student's private implementation.